# Adding UNC Links to Sharepoint Web Based Content

Tags: hyperlink

Trying to find a working solution from a development perspective for this issue.  Chrome/Firefox seem to block UNC (local/network hyperlink paths).  I have a few tools and files (mainly XLS spreadsheets) on a corporate file server that I want to link in my content.

These work fine in IE as there isn't any security protection.  I know you can add to trusted sites - but this doesn't work when dealing with a large user base - want something form the dev-side to take care of this.

The file server doesn't seem to have WebDAV or IIS support or anything so we can't try http://server/filepath/file.ext links.

My question; what options do I have, if any?  Is there a javascript or ASP workaround - something that you can provide an ahref-tag with onclick-function which starts the download or opens the share overriding the security protection?

Thanks